# Read multiple different columns in a CSV file and match different column names to a unified variable

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I have a Python script that uses variables such as "Phone", "gas_type",  and "car" all throughout the script. The script reads in from an csv file and if the column names are "Phone", "gas type",  and/or "car" the script matches the column to the respective variables.

This script works great if it  has a data set that has column exactly matching "Phone", "gas type",  and "car" ,however, I want the script to work with other datasets that have columns of the same type of values ( they are phone values, gas type values, and car values, but the column names are different).

For example, instead of "Phone", the column name could "mobile", or "celluar" but represent the same type of data. Instead of gas type, the column header could say "phone type", instead of "car", the column header could say "vehicle", or "automobile".

I want it so whenever my python script tries to find a column named "Phone", "gas_type",  and "car", which are variables used throughout the script, it knows that the header  spelling could be something else but mean the same thing, maybe by creating a python dictionary that I could add to whenever I encounter a new column name that matches "Phone", "gas_type" or "car".  Can someone help me create a function that can do this? I just do not know how I would set up the dictionary or another way that works best for my problem.

Here is what part of my script looks like:

```
 readin=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
 for column in readin.columns:
    # then I have a bunch of code  with "Phone", "gas_type" and "car" variables that does things # 
      like:     
    if column in ["Phone", "gas_type",  and "car"]: pass
```

As well as code that looks like :

```
 readin['Phone'] = df['Phone'].apply(str)
```

I am looking for a universal function that says whenever "Phone"  is listed as a variable in  another function in my code, the code knows to look up in the data for "mobile" and "cellular" or ect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

You can split them manually:

```
   if column in ["Phone", "mobile", "cellular"]:
        # function that handles phone data
    elif column in ["car", "vehicle", "automobile"]:
        # function that handles car data
    ... etc
```

Comment: I am more looking for a universal function that says whenever "Phone"  is listed as a variable in my code, the code knows to look up in the data for "mobile" and "cellular" or ect.